# How to parse a text box string into values in ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to parse a tab delimited text string (from a TextBox) into values. The idea is a user can copy and paste. I've had a good search around the net and I am struggling.

Here is an example of the textbox string:

```
Compressed Bright Spodumain 30  Spodumain           840 m3
Compressed Crimson Arkonor  1   Arkonor         8.80 m3
Compressed Crystalline Crokite  867 Crokite         6,771.27 m3
```

I would like to collect all 4 values but most importantly I must collect the first two "Compressed Bright Spodumain 30". I need to be able to add lines together as well for example if there where 2 "Compressed Bright Spodumain  30" lines it would add the number value together.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the text into rows with enter (carriage return) and then split the rows on the tab delimiter.

```
'check if the textbox actually contains text
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then

    'split the text in separate rows
    Dim rows() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {""& vbCrLf, ""& vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)

    'loop all the rows
    For Each row As String In rows

        'split the row in separate items
        Dim items() As String = row.Split(vbTab)

        'loop all the individual items
        For Each item As String In items
            Label1.Text = (Label1.Text + (item.Trim + "<br>"))
        Next
    Next
End If
```

**C#**

```
//check if the textbox actually contains text
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
{
    //split the text in separate rows
    string[] rows = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    //loop all the rows
    foreach (string row in rows)
    {
        //split the row in separate items
        string [] items = row.Split('\t');

        //loop all the individual items
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            Label1.Text += item.Trim() + "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `TextBox1.Text.Spli` because it already has property `lines`

Comment: The `lines` property is Winforms, not Webforms.

Comment: I missed - its the web forms!