# How to extract the last word from a sentence entered into a vb.net text box

Tags: vb.net

I need to write code to check the first letter of the last word entered into a text box. How do I do this in vb.net?

Comment: Of course it's difficult when starting out, but I had to downvote this question because as it was originally stated, was not really a specific question about a specific function, with any example code that showed initial efforts, or that helped give folks something to work with. Additionally there are answers to similar questions on the site that could point you in the right direction:. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745008/how-to-parse-a-text-box-string-into-values-in-asp-net-vb-net

Comment: What have you already tried?  How is it failing?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do that using linq:

```
Imports System.Linq
...

Dim text as String = textbox1.Text

If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) Then 'text can't be null or empty
     Return
End If

Dim firstLetterOfLastWord As String = text.Split(" ").LastOrDefault().FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

In generall @fsbflavio's code is correct, but it can be simplified in a oneliner:

```
Dim firstLetterOfLastWord As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last().FirstOrDefault()
```

If the textbox is empty (it can be an empty string), it will return `vbNullChar`. Otherwise, it will return the first letter of the last word.

Answer (score 1):

@fsbflavio has provided neat solution but it's so neat, it is likely your teacher will know you haven't done it yourself.

A more clumsy, step by step solution would be:

```
    Dim text As String = textbox1.Text

    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) Then 'text can't be null or empty
        Return ""
    Else
        Dim words As String() = text.Split(" ")
        Dim NumberOfWords As Integer = words.Length
        Dim LastWord = words(NumberOfWords - 1) 'Remember arrays start at index 0
        Dim FirstLetter As String = LastWord.Substring(0, 1)
        Return FirstLetter 
    End If
```

Not as elegant but it does show your workings.  Seeing it broken down step by step like this, maybe next time you should have a try yourself first & only ask here when you meet a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to generate an array of strings.
Get the last white space index - using [String.SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) and [String.LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof) together - increment by 1 its position and take a sub-string of length 1:

```
Dim theFirstOfTheLast = someText.Substring(someText.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1, 1)
```